# Datepicker with Past Dates and Sunday disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to have a datepicker calender with Sundays and days that has been past be disabled.

Currently I am using this code which I found here in Stackoverflow.

```
<script>
$( function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
});
} );
</script>
```

This does disable the Sundays which is exactly what I want. But how do I disable past dates as well?

From reading the other similar questions, I believe it should be 'mindate' that I should use, but I don't know how to write it with the following code above. Please do teach me. Thank you.

Comment: minDate: new Date() //for disable past dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code :

```
 $( function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(),
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 0), ''];
        }
    });
    } );
```

Comment: This works exactly the way I wanted, it disables Sundays as well as past dates. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
$( "#noSunday" ).datepicker({ 
        beforeShowDay: noSunday,
        minDate: 0
});
 

function noSunday(date){ 
          var day = date.getDay(); 
                      return [(day > 0), '']; 
      };
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<input id="noSunday" type="text">
```